# How to delete records in JPA @ManyToMany relationship?

Tags: java, sql, jpa, many-to-many, openjpa

I have defined a unidirectional ManyToMany relationship like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ODE_PROCESS_INSTANCE")
Public class ProcessInstanceDAOImpl extends OpenJPADAO implements ProcessInstanceDAO {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "ID")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long _instanceId;

  @ManyToMany(targetEntity = PolicyAttachmentDAOImpl.class)
  private Collection<PolicyAttachmentDAO> _policyAttachments = new ArrayList<PolicyAttachmentDAO>();

  public ProcessInstanceDAOImpl() {
  }

  public Collection<PolicyAttachmentDAO> getPolicyAttachments(){
    return _policyAttachments;
  }

  public void setPolicyAttachments(Collection<PolicyAttachmentDAO> policyAttachments){
    _policyAttachments = policyAttachments;
    getEM().merge(this);
    getEM().flush();
  }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ODE_POLICY_ATTACHMENT")
public class PolicyAttachmentDAOImpl extends OpenJPADAO implements PolicyAttachmentDAO{
  @Id
  @Column(name = "POLICYATTACHMENT_ID")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long _attachmentId;

  @Basic
  @Column(name = "POLICYATTACHMENT_NAME")
  private String _attachmentName;

  public PolicyAttachmentDAOImpl(String policyAttachmentName) {
    _attachmentName = policyAttachmentName;
  }

  public void deletePolicyAttachment(){
    //delete policy attachment DAO
getEM().remove(this);
getEM().flush();
  }
}
```

The join table is created. The problem is that when I delete a record from ODE_POLICY_ATTACHMENT the join table is not updated. How can I solve this problem?

This is how I add to the ta

```
Collection<PolicyAttachmentDAO> policyAttachments = new ArrayList<PolicyAttachmentDAO>();

attachmentDAO = new PolicyAttachmentDAOImpl("attachment_1");
policyAttachments.add(attachmentDAO);

attachmentDAO = new PolicyAttachmentDAOImpl("attachment_2");
policyAttachments.add(attachmentDAO);

attachmentDAO = new PolicyAttachmentDAOImpl("attachment_3");
policyAttachments.add(attachmentDAO);

//inst is an exisiting ProcessInstanceDAOImpl
inst.setPolicyAttachments(policyAttachments);
```

To delete a record from "ODE_PROCESS_INSTANCE" table I call the method deletePolicyAttachment() on a PolicyAttachmentDAOImpl object.

Comment: Are you sure that the `table` is not updated or the `runtime relationships` between the objects ? Because in JPA, the programmer is responsible for managing the `runtime relationships` of the entities. This will be helpful : http://blog.xebia.com/2009/03/16/jpa-implementation-patterns-bidirectional-assocations/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The join table is what maps the many to many association. It's what allows Hibernate to know that some attachment is linked to some process. So, if you don't want an attachment to be referenced in the join table, that means that you don't want the attachment linked to any process anymore. So the answer is simple: find all the processes having the attachment in their collection, and remove the attachment from their collection:

```
process.getPolicyAttachments().remove(theAttachment);
```

Side note: your naming is awful. Prepending an underscore to fields is not a standard convention, and will force you to add this leading underscore in all your queries. And what you have there are not DAOs, but entities. DAOs are the objects used to query and update the databases. Entities are the persistent objects returned by the DAOs. And you should not merge and flush each time you change the attachments of a process. Merging is rarely necessary, and flushing almost never, and this shouldn't be done by an entity anyway, which shouldn't access the EM at all.

Comment: I am a beginner. Is what you wrote valid if I use OpenJPA instead of Hibernate? What should I use insted of "merge" and "flush" when I change the attachments of a process instance? I have done it like that because I fallowed the example from here http://blog.jbaysolutions.com/2012/12/17/jpa-2-relationships-many-to-many/

Comment: JPA is JPA. Yes, it's valid. You shouldn't use anything. merge is used to copy the state of an detached entity to an attached entity. That's not the case here. flush() is used to force the JPA engine to execute all its insert, update and delete queries now, instead of waiting until it does it when necessary, automatically.